# Kendo Grid dynamic columns Endless scrolling implementation ASP.NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have implemented Kendo Grid paging with a class. But now I am trying to bind it with dynamic columns SQL table paging the issue is on the second scroll/page it failed the method `var data = dt.ToDataSourceResult(request);` `data.Data` is empty

Here is the complete code 
Razor page

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<dynamic>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(sc => sc.Endless(true))
    .Filterable()
    .Groupable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(100)
            .Model(model =>
            {
                var id = "Id";
                model.Id(id);
            })
            .Read(read => read.Action("Data_Read", "DynamicColumn"))
        )
)
```

Controller

```
 public IActionResult Data_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
 {
     var dt = GetViewsData(request.PageSize, request.Page);
     var data = dt.ToDataSourceResult(request);
     var viewData = new DataSourceResult()
     {
         Data = data.Data, //this return NULL on the second page/scroll request
         Total = 181480 //total rows of table, just make it static
     };
     return Json(viewData);
 }

public DataTable GetViewsData(int pageSize, int page)
    {

        try
        {
            int offSet = (page - 1) * 100;
            string connString = "Server=.; Database=TheVault_VMC; Trusted_Connection=true; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; Encrypt=False;";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetData", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OFFSetRows", offSet);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageSize", pageSize);
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            var dataTable = new DataTable();

            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            dataAdapter.FillSchema(dataTable, SchemaType.Mapped);
            con.Close();
            return dataTable;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

}
```

Database stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetData] 
   @OFFSetRows INT,
   @PageSize INT
AS
BEGIN    
    SELECT 
         Id, [Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4], [Column5],[Column6]
    FROM
        [StagingDetail]
    ORDER BY 
        Id
    OFFSET @OFFSetRows ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
END
```

The issue is the function `ToDataSourceResult()` returns NULL on the second request.

```
var data = dt.ToDataSourceResult(request);
var viewData = new DataSourceResult()
{
    Data = data.Data,
    Total = 181480
};
```

Any clue what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: **Side note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, converted the Datatable to the dynamic Array and then passed it to the data of the DataSourceResult() class.

```
 public IActionResult Data_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
  {
      var dt = GetViewsData(request.PageSize, request.Page);
      var arr = ToDynamic(dt);
      var viewData = new DataSourceResult()
      {
       Data = arr,
       Total = 181480
      };
      return Json(viewData);
  }


  private static List<dynamic> ToDynamic(DataTable dt)
  {
      var dynamicDt = new List<dynamic>();
      foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      {
          dynamic dyn = new ExpandoObject();
          dynamicDt.Add(dyn);
          foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
          {
              var dic = (IDictionary<string, object>)dyn;
              dic[column.ColumnName] = row[column];
          }
      }
      return dynamicDt;
  }
```